# Facebook like/react button animation

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

How to create an animation similar to that performed when we choose any react (which opens when we long press the like icon)?
The specific react icon jumps and replaces the like icon.
I have tried BounceInterpolator and few other interpolators but they actually don't fulfil my requirements. 
Please help as I am a noobie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this [library](https://github.com/dbof10/FBReaction?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=5490) to get your desired result, it will look something like this

[image]

Comment: I don't think so that this is a library...